# Java Game Networking Erratic Errors

Tags: java, networking, udp

I'm pretty much at a total loss here.  I tried all day yesterday and all night last night to figure out what the hell is wrong with my code but now I'm thinking there's actually a little gremlin in my computer nibbling on the CPU.  I was following along with this tutorial series:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1p21JWa_8s&list=ELp5mgUw5g9EY

until I decided to pause it and make my own custom Packet class.  It was working fine for a while but then some really weird stuff started to happen.  Basically what's happening is the data sent between client and server is getting jumbled up somehow when it is received (I confirmed that the data was correct before it was sent).  This happens at seemingly random points and now I'm baffled

For example I had the line:

```
System.out.println( m_Game.m_aConnectedPlayers[ intPlayerID ].GetUserName( ) + " has joined." );
```

and changed it to

```
System.out.println( m_Game.m_aConnectedPlayers[ intPlayerID ].GetUserName( ) + "(" + intPlayerID + ") has joined." );
```

to include the player ID, and then the packet data was getting scrambled up when I connected to the server with a third client.  Also even as I typed this I decided to go back and test it again and the error stopped happening.  I'll grant +100 internet points to whoever can somehow figure this out.  Here is my entire project (excuse my messy code)
http://www.mediafire.com/?9w6god1cjsnwbnf

Comment: "I'll grant +100 internet points" Irrelevant to the problem, impossible without a bounty. Also please paste the output of each.

Comment: *"I was following along with this tutorial series:

http:www.youtube..."*  It astonishes me when people seem to think they can learn to program by watching videos.  :-(

Comment: Have you sniffed the data on the wire? (wireshark/Fiddler). Also - where is the code hosted?

Comment: The output of these lines were as expected "Joe" and "Joe(0)".  Except that when I used the second line, the packet data was scrambled later on in the code

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I'm pretty sure it is not the only source the OP used... ;)

Comment: *"Here is my entire project.."*  No thanks.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Yeah that astonishes me too Andrew, I learned from my college professors who were constructive and helpful

Comment: Have you tried a different format i.e. `.GetUserName( ) + intPlayerID + " has joined."` dropping the `()`?

Comment: Nope I didn't get a chance to try a different format Paul and now the error has vanished mysteriously.  I guess I should record my progress and wait for it to happen again so I can replicate it. Also, I've never used wireshark or fiddler but I'll look into it

Comment: Also... are you ABSOLUTELY sure this wasn't happening before you added the concatentation. It seems highly unlikely that adding a system.out.println code would mung networking code.

Comment: Yeah Paul that's what I thought too.  But I'm absolutely positive that it was not happening before, and after it was happening. I even removed it and added it back a couple times to confirm.  The same kind of thing has happened before but I just dismissed it, since it disappeared the same way this error has

Comment: I had a look at the net code and the first thing that struck me is the use of UDP (DatagramSocket). This could end up in garbled data due to UDP not having flow control though without firing up the project and doing network analysis I can't say for sure. Very odd though that this would result from a `out` call though as I said...

Comment: Based on what I'm reading, it sounds like a bad idea to send multiple packets in quick succession that I need to arrive in order with UDP, which is what I'm doing.  Is it a better idea to condense data into one UDP packet then split it up after it's received?  For example something like 

byte[ ] { Packet ID, value 1, value 1, value 1, value 2, value 2, value 2, } 
as opposed to 
byte[ ] { Packet ID }
byte[ ] { value 1, value 1, value 1 }
byte[ ] { value 2, value 2, value 2, }

If so then what kind of conventions should I use to indicate the data type and the start/end of a value?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem might be, but problems I've had doing much the same thing:

If you use ObjectOutput/ObjectInput be sure call the `reset` method after each write.  Object output only writes a single object between resets, so if you send it, change the values, and send it again, the other end will receive only the old values.  It's an ingenious way to send whole object graphs, but it makes a mess of what you're trying to do.

If you're writing with multiple multiple threads, there's a good chance they're not running in the order you think they are.